# Texture not displaying in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

The triangle i drew with OpenGL can't be displayed. When i debug my code it's only the white background appeared. Can anyone help me?

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <SOIL.h>

const float piOver180 = 0.0174532925f;
float heading;
float xPos;
float zPos;

//declarations
GLuint filter;
GLuint texture[3];

int width = 720;
int height = 540;

void init();
void display();
void drawTriangle();
void reshape(int width, int height);
```

this is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Muzeum");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
}


void init()
{
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
        "wallpaper.bmp",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
        );
    texture[1] = texture[2] = texture[0];

    if (texture[0] == 0 || texture[1] == 0 || texture[2] == 0)
    {
        printf("SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result());
        exit(0);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
}
```

my display function

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLfloat xTrans = -xPos;
    GLfloat yTrans = -walk - 0.25f;
    GLfloat zTrans = -zPos;
    GLfloat sceneRotY = 360.0f - yRot;

    glTranslatef(xTrans, yTrans, zTrans);

    drawTriangle();
glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

where i draw my triangle

```
void drawTriangle()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(-3.0f, 0.0f);  glVertex3f(-3.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(-3.0f, 0.0f);  glVertex3f(-3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(3.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(3.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(-3.0f, 0.0f);  glVertex3f(-3.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(3.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(-3.0f, 6.0f, 6.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(3.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(3.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(40.0f, (GLdouble)width / (GLdouble)height, 0.5f, 20.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

What i want to do is a room with texture-mapped, now this is only my floor part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your geometry is not in your field of view. Your `gluPerspective()` call sets up a projection transformation with a camera placed on the origin, and pointing in the negative z-direction. With the values for the near and far planes, it will show z-values in the range from -0.5 to -20.0. All the z-values of your geometry are in the range 0.0 to 6.0, so all your geometry is behind the camera.

I tried most of your code, and I got things showing up by adding a translation to the modelview transformation. For example, adding a line after the first two lines of the `display()` function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
```

A few more things that could get in your way:

- No call to `glutInit()`. I figure you have that in the original code.
- `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is not a legal value for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`. This must be `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST`. `glGetError()` is your friend!
- Fortunately you didn't enable blending, because your `glBlendFunc()` call, in combination with a white clear color, would prevent anything from being drawn. You would add to white, and that whole whiter than white thing only works in detergent commercials. ;)
- Clearing alpha to 1.0, as you do with the last argument of `glClearColor()` is quite unusual. Doesn't really hurt for now, since you only use an RGB framebuffer, and do not blend with destination alpha.
- `glFlush()` before `glutSwapBuffers()` is redundant, and only hurts performance.